# How to remove a <li> or check/uncheck a <li> by clicking in a respective icon that is inside of a span that is inside of that li?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this situation, 
1- I want to remove a li that as a span inside with two icons: One is to check or uncheck the respective li and the other one is to erase that li.
2- I want also to check or uncheck that li by clicking on the icon(check icon) but also clicking on the li.

I wanted to do with event delegation by putting the addEventListener in ul but I don't know how to do it the code.
I don't have any JS code,  I was expecting you to help me

Thank you

```js
//delegation events 
//1-how to remove the li by clicking in icon with a class 'cross'?
//2-how to check or uncheck the li by clicking on the icon with a class 'check' and also by clicking in that li and showing or hiding the icon 'check'?

ul.addEventListener ('click',function())


//or by using the addEventListener in iconCross, how can I remove the li?
 // and by using the addEventListener in icon check, how can I check/uncheck the li by clicking on the icon and also on the li?

const iconCross = document.querySelectorAll('.cross')

iconCross.addEventListener('click',function())
```

```css
li{

display:flex;
align-content:center;
justify-contnt:space-between;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
      <i class="check"></i>
      <i class="cross"></i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `remove()` to remove an element from the DOM. Here, your `li` is two levels up, to have to get reference using `parentElement` and then call the `remove()`

```js
let withRemove = document.querySelectorAll('.with-remove .cross')

withRemove.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  });
});

const withClass = document.querySelectorAll('.with-class .cross')

withClass.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="with-remove">
  <li>
    <span>
      <i class="check">check1</i>
      <i class="cross">cross1</i>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <i class="check">check2</i>
      <i class="cross">cross2</i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="with-class">
  <li>
    <span>
      <i class="check">check11</i>
      <i class="cross">cross11</i>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <i class="check">check22</i>
      <i class="cross">cross22</i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you =) I didn't know that I could repeat parentNode twice up to two levels .thank you so much  for your kindness

Comment: I tried your solution but didn´t work in my code. I may have done something wrong . can I send to you my code for you to check out what I did wrong ? And maybe you can see also the other icon? I used SVG images for icon .

Comment: How are you going to send me your code? The best option is to update the post with your code or do a sample fiddle

Comment: I did once and it confused people for what I wanted  because its a lot of code.  but the important is there and didnt worked  with what you were saying. can you give me an example sample in the fiddle ?

Comment: Well, the above is an example in a fiddle mate. Its quite straight forward. Make sure your svg has the correct class name as in the example

Comment: thank you but is missing the other part that I asked about the hide/show the icon with the class .check by clicking on the li or in icon himself. the rest it worked but I used event delegation in ul to not use looping and it will be heavy if I insert 40 to - do tasks.

Comment: Have edited the code to hide using class, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//delegation events 
//1-how to remove the li by clicking in icon with a class 'cross'?
//2-how to check or uncheck the li by clicking on the icon with a class 'check' and also by clicking in that li and showing or hiding the icon 'check'?



//or by using the addEventListener in iconCross, how can I remove the li?
 // and by using the addEventListener in icon check, how can I check/uncheck the li by clicking on the icon and also on the li?
const iconCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('check')

iconCheck[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
  iconCheck[0].parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("check-li")
})

const iconCross = document.getElementsByClassName('cross')

iconCross[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
  iconCross[0].parentElement.parentElement.remove()
})
```

```css
li{
display: flex;
align-content: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

li.check-li{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="check-li">
    <span>
      <i class="check">check</i>
      <i class="cross">cross</i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it can´t be with [0] index because I want to do in all lis that I want to remove or check and uncheck. and also the check class is for the icon with his proprieties by showing the icon so there is no need to create that chek-li in the li.  because what  I wanted is to manipulate the icon with .check className by clicking on the li and also in the icon. not the opposite.

Comment: `const iconCheck = document.querySelectorAll('.check')

iconCheck.forEach(function(el) {
 el.addEventListener('click',function(element){
   this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("check-li")
})
})`

https://jsfiddle.net/9ogt2z7m/2/